# Timer with javascript and C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to create a timer in an ASP.NET web page.

I have tested some JavaScript code like:

```
window.onload = function WindowLoad(event) {
    setTimeout(function () { alert("DoIT") }, 60000);
}
```

and it works like expected but when I replace the `alert` with a call to a C# function like:

```
window.onload = function WindowLoad(event) {
    setTimeout(function () { <% doIt(); %> }, 60000);
}
```

the function works on the load of the page and not after the specified period.

Comment: I would suggest looking at Ajax for calling a Server Side function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**<% doIt() %>** runs during the server side process, not on client. If you want to do something on the server side you should create a webmethod and make a post to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this blog post, this should be what you are looking for: http://deebujacob.blogspot.com/2012/01/aspnet-ajax-web-method-call-using.html

It's like other people sad you can not call server side functions directly from javascript you have to make a request, that's is way good God gave as ajax :)